# Printing full path to all possible png files in directory

Tags: python, file, glob

I need to display all png files in directory 'images'. The problem  is there is subdirectory 'additional files' with one more png in it.

```
import glob
my_path = "images"
possible_files = os.path.join(my_path, "*.png")
for file in glob.glob(possible_files):
    print(file)
```

How can i display full path to all png files in this directory including png files in subdirectories without new loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.walk method.

```
import glob
import os

for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(YOURPATH):
    possible_files = os.path.join(dirpath, "*.png")
    for file in glob.glob(possible_files):
        print(file)
```

'filenames' gives you the name of the files and you can use 'dirpath' to and 'dirnames' to determine which directory they are from, so you can even include some sub directories and skip others.

Comment: i need to do it with glob.glob()

Comment: Then just put your code inside os.walk() so you can use glob() for all the subdirectories, check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

How about this? You are already using the os library.

```
my_path = "images"
out = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in glob.glob(my_path+"\\**\\*.png", recursive=True)]
```

`out` is a list with all `png` files with fullpath (with subdirectories)